# Swift use selector argument like a closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I was just wondering if it was possible to pass a function to a button action (which is usually a selector).

For example, normally I'd say:

```
UIBarButtonItem(title: "Press", style: .Done, target: self, action: "functionToCall")

func functionToCall() {
    // Do something
}
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to do something like:

```
UIBarButtonItem(title: "Press", style: .Done, target: self, action: {
    // Do Something
})
```

Reason I want to do this is because my function is super simple and it seems like it would be neater and more Swift-like what with the emphasis they are placing on closures.

Answer (score 21):

Here's an updated solution for Swift 3.

```
class BlockBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    private var actionHandler: (() -> Void)?

    convenience init(title: String?, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style, actionHandler: (() -> Void)?) {
        self.init(title: title, style: style, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed))
        self.target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    convenience init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style, actionHandler: (() -> Void)?) {
        self.init(image: image, style: style, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed))
        self.target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    @objc func barButtonItemPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        actionHandler?()
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work for objective-c property blocks? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172472/how-to-invoke-objective-c-block-property-in-swift

Comment: Yes you should be able to do something similar with objective-c.

Comment: as u can see in  the question under the link, it looks like not possible. Maybe u know why?)

Comment: Doesn't `func barButtonItemPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem)` need to be prefixed with `@objc` to exposed it to Objective-C? Pretty sure the compiler gives you a warning otherwise.

Answer (score 18):

This is an alternative solution without subclassing:

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    private struct AssociatedObject {
        static var key = "action_closure_key"
    }

    var actionClosure: (()->Void)? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObject.key) as? ()->Void
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObject.key, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            target = self
            action = #selector(didTapButton(sender:))
        }
    }

    @objc func didTapButton(sender: Any) {
        actionClosure?()
    }
}
```

It relies on the associated objects from the Objective-C runtime to add a closure/block property.

When set, it changes the target to itself and points the selector to a new function that calls the closure if it exists.

With this, in any moment you can just set the `actionClosure` of any `UIBarButtonItem` and expect everything to work, here's an example:

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(
    barButtonSystemItem: .action,
    target: nil, action: nil
)
button.actionClosure = {
    print("hello")
}
```

Comment: Maybe should be .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC ?

Comment: In 2023 Swift Format says to use `enum AssociatedObject` instead but anyway... helpful, thanks for this!

Comment: `&AssociatedObject.key` now warns `Forming 'UnsafeRawPointer' to an inout variable of type String exposes the internal representation rather than the string contents`.

Answer (score 14):

- Updated for Swift 5.
- Implements all of the convenience initializers that have targets.
- Adds a `typealias` for the function signature to clean up the syntax.
- Passes the `UIBarButtonItem` into the action handler in keeping with Cocoa conventions.

```
import UIKit

class SwiftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    typealias ActionHandler = (UIBarButtonItem) -> Void

    private var actionHandler: ActionHandler?

    convenience init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style, actionHandler: ActionHandler?) {
        self.init(image: image, style: style, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed(sender:)))
        target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    convenience init(title: String?, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style, actionHandler: ActionHandler?) {
        self.init(title: title, style: style, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed(sender:)))
        target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    convenience init(barButtonSystemItem systemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem, actionHandler: ActionHandler?) {
        self.init(barButtonSystemItem: systemItem, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed(sender:)))
        target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    @objc func barButtonItemPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        actionHandler?(sender)
    }
}
```

Comment: cute. Why not make the block non-optional in the inits? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A post on Reddit explains a solution for this with a custom component - https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/3fjzap/creating_button_action_programatically_using

To use it though I had to add the Button programatically rather than through storyboard. Here was how I did it.

```
let tempVariableIWantToReference = "Classy"

navigationTitle.leftBarButtonItem = BlockBarButtonItem.init(
   title: "< Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, 
   actionHandler: { () -> Void in
       print("Hey I'm in a closure")
       print("I can even reference temporary variables. \(self.tempVariableIWantToReference)!!!")
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly it is not possible with Apple provided initialisers. The way this works in the background is with reflection, and providing a closure is something completely different which isn't currently supported.

You might be able to create a custom solution with some hacking or Apple may introduce that in the future.