# Use closure instead selector argument for UIBarButtonItem BUT without using weak self

Tags: ios, swift, closures, uibarbuttonitem, retain-cycle

In order to use closure in argument of `UIBarButtonItem` I am using a subclass:

```
class ActionBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    private var actionHandler: (() -> Void)?

    convenience init(title: String?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, actionHandler: (() -> Void)?) {
        self.init(title: title, style: style, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed))
        self.target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    convenience init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, actionHandler: (() -> Void)?) {
        self.init(image: image, style: style, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed))
        self.target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    @objc func barButtonItemPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        actionHandler?()
    }
}
```

but now I need to weak `[weak self]` :

```
    self.add(barButton: .menu, position: .left) { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
        strongSelf.openMenu()
    }
```

is there a way to still use closure as selector but not save the closure to avoid using weak self everywhere and you may forget it somewhere ?

Comment: If you don't save the closure then how can it be executed later, when the button is pressed?

Comment: Just a sidenote: what you call weakSelf in the guard let is actually a strong self already :)

Comment: @MartinR so no way to use closure without using weak self what about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44037534/1836115

Comment: @BencePattogato mistake corrected

Comment: @iOSGeek:  `button.actionClosure = { self.doSomething() }` from that example would also keep a strong reference to self, causing a retain cycle, so you would capture self weakly as well in that solution

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

You have to save the closure if you're going to call it later. If you're saving a closure, and that closure refers to `self`, you should make `self` part of a capture list to avoid a retain cycle. That's what capture lists are for, and is the correct coding pattern for this situation.

Any time you refer to self in a closure you need to stop and think about retain cycles.